# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml”: “featured”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I know there was many question about this error, and there were always answers about

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

But my _Layout.cshtml file doesn't have that section in it. 
My file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Główna", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Uzytkownicy", "Index", "Database")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("O systemie", "About", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <p>Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to:

1. enter '"scripts", required: false' on @RenderBody(),
2. delete scripts from head section
3. put @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) in head section, above the scripts.

None of this helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section is like a placeholder you define inside your layout and inject some real content to that from your specific view. When the page runs, the content you passed from your page's section will be injected to the place where `RenderSection()` is called in your layout.

Looks like your view is passing something via the `featured` section, but your layout does not have a definition of the "featured" section. So you need to either add it to the layout file

```
<body>
    <section id="main">

        @RenderBody()

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

    </section>
</body>
```

Or delete the `featured section` code from your specific view.

You probably need to keep the `@RenderSection("scripts",required:false)` in your layout which will help you to include page specific javascript from your specific views.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted render section from my views and it helped :)